# Regex to find if a string contains all numbers 0-9 be it in any order

Tags: python, regex

Regex to find if a string contains all numbers 0-9 be it in any order.
Can anyone help?

Suppose I have a string- "01230912747238507156" This has all characters from 0-9. So I should get True.

Comment: The question is not clear at all, what do you want to achieve, what are the examples of your strings?

Comment: It'd be much easier to do this without a regex than with. Just write some Python that iterates each char in the string and remembers if it's seen every digit 0-9.

Comment: Why do this with a regex?

Comment: Suppose I have a string- "0123091274723507156" This has all characters from 0-9. So I should get True.

Comment: I cannot use a loop. I need to do this with regex.

Comment: Can anyone say how to do this with only regex?

Comment: 0123091274723507156, no 8.

Comment: `{n for n in s if n in '1234567890'} == {'%i' % i for i in range(10)}`

Comment: You are using a look Karlson

Comment: Ok, then take this `set(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s)) == set(map(str, range(10)))` :)

Comment: Very demanding for someone asking us to do his homework for him.

Comment: `^(?=.*1.*)(?=.*2.*)(?=.*3.*)(?=.*4.*)(?=.*5.*)(?=.*6.*)(?=.*7.*)(?=.*8.*)(?=.*9.*)(?=.*0.*)\d+$`

Positive look aheads are definitely for you here.

https://regex101.com/r/fl2xd8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution can handle all sorts of strings, not only numeric characters.

```
s1 = 'ABC0123091274723507156XYZ' # without 8
s2 = 'ABC0123091274723507156XYZ8'

len(set("".join(re.findall(r'([\d])', s1)))) == 10 # False
len(set("".join(re.findall(r'([\d])', s2)))) == 10 # True
```

How it works:

Find all digits in the string with regex `findall`. Join all matches to one string and get unique characters by putting it in a `set`. Then count the length of the `set`. If all digits are represented the length will be 10.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python's built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##Fcm9CoAgFAbQvae4OCl8gz@pOfQk0dASCXELdenprbYD537acbHrvdJMQhvrdDI2jtE6r6PxQQz8zaJhYOEwwiMgYkJah7tkbnI7T1lbkVlRZqq0X4XyT1aq9xc)

```
s = "0123091274723507156"
n = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(all(str(i) in s for i in n))
```

You could also replace `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` with `list(range(0,10))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a counter like this

```
string = "01230912747235071568"

cnt = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    if str(i) in string:
        print(i)
        cnt += 1

print(cnt)
```

If you are really looking for a regex solution (learning purposes?), you could use multiple lookaheads (not advisable, really redundant code):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'^(?=^0*0)(?=^1*1)(?=^2*2)(and so on...).+$')
```

That is:

```
(?=not_one zero or more times, then one)...
```

Comment: No loops. I mentioned before

Comment: @AbhisekRoy: See the updated answer then.

Comment: I just want to check if a string has all numbers 0-9, anywhere in the string. It has to be written in regex. And I am coding in Python.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' This is the error that your code is giving @Jan

Comment: @AbhisekRoy There is no "No loops" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `.isdigit()` to filter for non numbers it returns a boolean.

This has the limitation of only working for contiguous numbers/integers.

Comment: only if the string doesn't contain any non-numeric characters

Comment: The string has all numbers only. I just need to find if it has all the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 somewhere or the other in the string.